# Ionic requests return 404 only on android, in Chrome it works fine

Tags: android, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

So, i have cloned the tutorial app repo from ionic. I ran

```
ionic start conference sidemenu
```

and then i added a simple $http.get('myserver')(I tried with ngResources too).

It worked perfect on chrome, I got all the data back but on angular i only got null data and 404 status on any request I tried to do.

Note: I tried with my hosted server and with a local one. Both fail on Android. 
Server is a node.js REST API.

Nothing is printed on the console, so the request does not even get to the server.

Has anyone experienced that or could tell me how can I debug Android apps built with Ionic?

EDIT 1: I don`t know why do you need it but here it is

```
$http.get('http://server.com/route').success(function (data) {
            //handle success
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            // handle error
        });
```

Comment: please add some code  refering your your service and how you call it with angular.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The thing is that there were some major changes in Cordova 4.0.0:

> Major Changes
>   [...]
>   -  Whitelist functionality is now provided via plugin (CB-7747) The
>      whitelist has been enhanced to be more secure and configurable
>      Setting of Content-Security-Policy is now supported by the framework
>      (see details in plugin readme) You will need to add the new
>      cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin Legacy whitelist behaviour is still
>      available via plugin (although not recommended).

So I installed the [Cordova Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). And added

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

in my `config.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks. I searched for this solution more than 2 days. I cannot understand, why the Cordova is not throwing exception if access origin is not defined.

Comment: I found that I also had to add a Content-Security-Policy meta tag, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/30209484/498949

Comment: I upvoted because it gave me definitely the push in the direction that I needed, the fix works but obviously still had to adjust it to not go all in with a wildcard. For security reasons obviously.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the problem was with `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin. I just removed the plugin and added it. Also enabled any requests by adding this code 
`<access origin="*" />` in `config.xml`. Please find below commands:

You need to remove existing plugin by using below command:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Then just add it by using below command:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the solutions before doesn't work on ionic 3.
Thanks @rickie finally a real solution three days of maddness!!! and now is ok.  Go to `\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java` and comment this rows:

```java
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
        // Check the against the whitelist and lock out access to the WebView directory
        // Changing this will cause problems for your application
      /*  if (!parentEngine.pluginManager.shouldAllowRequest(url)) {
            LOG.w(TAG, "URL blocked by whitelist: " + url);
            // Results in a 404.
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
        }*/

        CordovaResourceApi resourceApi = parentEngine.resourceApi;
        Uri origUri = Uri.parse(url);
        // Allow plugins to intercept WebView requests.
        Uri remappedUri = resourceApi.remapUri(origUri);

        if (!origUri.equals(remappedUri) || needsSpecialsInAssetUrlFix(origUri) || needsKitKatContentUrlFix(origUri)) {
            CordovaResourceApi.OpenForReadResult result = resourceApi.openForRead(remappedUri, true);
            return new WebResourceResponse(result.mimeType, "UTF-8", result.inputStream);
        }
        // If we don't need to special-case the request, let the browser load it.
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!(e instanceof FileNotFoundException)) {
            LOG.e(TAG, "Error occurred while loading a file (returning a 404).", e);
        }
        // Results in a 404.
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local content you should, when cordova compile is a **www** folder, they are there assets and other folder for you implement the apk or equivalent iOS

i.e

```
<img src="assets/images/{your-file-name}">
```