# ionic3 - android platform cannot get http data from backend

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

After I format my MAC, I copy and paste my ionic3 project from my hard disk, and set up all environment successfully.

`ionic cordova build ios --prod` can build success, can run without problem and also can get data from backend.

when I run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` also build success without error showing but when run it in my android devices cannot get data from backend and also some function cannot used(I got a phone call function when I press it in android which is not working).

Don't know why can run and get data by IOS, but cannot get data when run in android devices(no this problem showing when I run before).

Run `ionic serve -l` in web also very nice without problem
[image]

And I already tried :

1. remove and rebuild android platform a lot of time, still cannot get data from backend!
2. build without --prod version, like `ionic cordova build android` also cannot get data.

Comment: do you get any console errors in android?

Comment: console in android studio?

Comment: read https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: you can debug ionic since it runs on webview

Comment: web console can? or have to get android console?

Comment: web console without error showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154515/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-suraj).

Comment: @suraj thanks a lot, problem solved already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem : `android platform cannot get http data from backend`

android console showing : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

My mistake is I uninstall **WhiteList cordova plugin**, because I think this plugin is unused...

So **reinstall WhiteList cordova plugin again** and android can get data from backend already.

whitelist plugin install : `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Also copy this in config.xml file `<allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />`

*reference：*[Ionic requests return 404 only on android, in Chrome it works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826971/ionic-requests-return-404-only-on-android-in-chrome-it-works-fine)